# Convert .ToHashset Result from (Of Char) to (Of String)?

Tags: vb.net, linq, hashset

I'm not real experienced in using Linq, and am trying to understand `.ToHashSet`.

I'm using VB for this.

I have this code:

```
' Import the list of Windows Classes to exclude; one per line.
Dim strRead As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Exclude.txt")

' Split the string into a string array
Dim strExcludes As String() = strRead.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

' Convert the String Array to a HashSet (Traditional Method)
Dim lList As New HashSet(Of String)(strExcludes)
```

This works as intended; I get each line from the text file into the HashSet as 1 line per Key.

Now, I want to see how to do the same using `.ToHashSet`. The following code seems to work fine with the exception of it returning as type `<Of Char>`, so I get each character in it's own Key, rather than each line in it's own Key.

```
' Convert the String Array to a HashSet (Using System.Linq Method) (Unfinished: Works, but needs to be converted from Char to String)
Dim lListLinq = strRead.ToHashSet()
```

I've Googled, and fought with it a bit, trying to get it to return as type `<Of String>`, but not much Google info out there for `.ToHashSet` for VB, or really much in C# either regarding this particular problem. I'm not seeing where to do the conversion; `.ToHashSet` itself also accepts no arguments.

Anyone know what I'm missing? I have a feeling it's something real simple slipping by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `ToHashSet()` on a string will yield a `HashSet(Of Char)` and will not give the expected result as you've witnessed.

Instead, what you need to do is split the string returned by `ReadAllText` and then call `ToHashSet()` on it to get a `HashSet(Of String)`.

```
strRead.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToHashSet()
```

Comment: I'm assuming I need to place that where `strExcludes` is on this line: `Dim lList As New HashSet(Of String)(strExcludes)`? What's the difference between adding the .ToHashSet to that line then, or just leaving it out, and putting the rest of the line there instead?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein what I am saying is if you call `strRead.ToHashSet`, this will return a `HashSet(Of Char)` where each element of the set is a single letter, which is not what you're after. So, in order to get a `HashSet(Of String)` you need to split the single string returned by `ReadAllText` to get each line separate, at this point you can then convert it into a `HashSet(Of String)` e.g. `Dim result as HashSet(Of String) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Exclude.txt").Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToHashSet()`.

Comment: I swear I'm not trying to be argumentative, lol, but that essentially seems to be the same thing. I will mark it as best answer, but I just want to clearly understand. If I do this: `Dim result As New HashSet(Of String)(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Exclude.txt").Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))` all I did was add `New` to the declaration, remove the = and place the line within parentheses, and remove the `.ToHashSet` and got the same result. I guess I was just hoping Linq would be slicker, lol.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Completely fine ;-).  You asked you wanted to experiment with `ToHashSet` and yes I agree with you the difference is so little... The only advantage I see with using `.ToHashSet` instead of `New HashSet(Of String)(...)` is that you can call `ToHashSet` directly on the `IEnumerable` chain which can lead to better readability and people have been making their own `ToHashSet` extension methods in the past so Microsoft decided to make it a method.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein another advantage is that `ToHashSet` is also shorter than `New HashSet(Of T)(...)` ;-)